# Hive substr with group by cause slow performance

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have a table which has about 300,000 records in each partition (ds).

When running the following query in hive (select with substr), it will hanging on the step: map = 0%

```
select t0.stat_date,t0.plat,t0.soh,t0.page_name,t0.component_name ,count(*) as num,user_id,t0.other_info
from (
    select substr(stat_time,1,8) as stat_date,user_id,city_id,soh,dept_id,dph,plat,page_name,component_name,cookie_id,other_info
    from db.table
    where ds=20170221 and plat='abc'
)t0
group by stat_date,plat,soh,page_name,component_name,other_info,t0.user_id
```

However, if I replace the inner query from **select substr(stat_time,1,8) as stat_date** to **select stat_time as stat_date**, it will execute normally.

**stat_time** is something formatted in YYYYMMDDHHmm = 201702210900

```
select t0.stat_date,t0.plat,t0.soh,t0.page_name,t0.component_name ,count(*) as num,user_id,t0.other_info
from (
    select stat_time as stat_date,user_id,city_id,soh,dept_id,dph,plat,page_name,component_name,cookie_id,other_info
    from db.table
    where ds=20170221 and plat='abc'
)t0
group by stat_date,plat,soh,page_name,component_name,other_info,t0.user_id
```

So why substr leads to slow performance?

--

Edit:

I changed mapred.child.java.opts in mapred-site.xml, and HADOOP_HEAPSIZE in hadoop-env.sh to 4G. And it succeed.

I guess either saving or calculating all the substr causes a lot heap.

If anybody knows why using a plain field value is less memory causing than substr, please leave a comment/answer.

Comment: "slow performance" Or "no performance"? It seems that the query hasn't start running and I doubt if it has any relation to the substr

Comment: instead of using substr why don't you use date function - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Comment: @mbaxi Stat_time doesn't have seconds, which mean if using date functions will require pre-processing data. It doesn't make sense to me that all the pre-processing steps plus a built-in date function is faster than substr (which is also a built-in function).

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I think you are right, this job stuck at the beginning. I actually changed mapred.child.java.opts in mapred-site.xml, and  HADOOP_HEAPSIZE in hadoop-env.sh to 4G. And it finally succeed.

Comment: Great :-) ............